# SQL Component internally resets CamelSqlUpdateCount to zero

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

Oddly enough, the SQL component reset the CamelSqlUpdateCount header value to zero when there is a 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' before a 'REPLACE SELECT'.

I ran in debug mode with a watcher on the header map. Yes the value is correct at first but it is set to zero in the process.

This situation does not occur with the JDBC component, only with the SQL component. Unfortunately, the JDBC component cannot be used in a "from".

working.sql

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE_B
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

non_working.sql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
REPLACE INTO TABLE_B
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Working route

```
.enrich("sql:working.sql") // CamelSqlUpdateCount header is set e.g. to 500
.process(MyClass::operation) // CamelSqlUpdateCount is still 500
```

Non-working route

```
.enrich("sql:non_working.sql") // CamelSqlUpdateCount header is set e.g. to 500
.process(MyClass::operation) // CamelSqlUpdateCount has been lost, it is zero
```

Camel version 3.12.0